# How to notify UI side from backend using WebApi?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, callback

I have to add text that shows the progress of the import. Right now we have the import bar to show progess but i need to add some text above the bar that say "Importing data- (# of # complete)."

For example, if we were importing 100 data, it might say "Importing data- (10 of 100 complete)."

Please suggest if any how we can show that in progress.

Comment: Is it web or desktop? WinForms, Wpf? Please provide more details

Comment: I am using Webapi to send list in request but i want a call back when it enters entry in db for each iteration of loop so that i can show the number of data successfully imported. – Ashutosh Adarsh 10 secs ago   edit

Comment: To not have minuses on your question add more details in it about techs you use and paraphrase the title in more specific, for example "How to notify UI side from backend using WebApi"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple solution, I think you can post your data by batches. Assume you have 100 data, then you post 10 data on each iteration, and OnSuccess function, you just update your UI. You may also need to be very careful for asynchronous requests and a rollback mechanism, it's somehow failed in an iteration, you need to erase your posted data.

Another approach is to go with some real time technologies, like [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

Hope my idea helps you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

After each import iteration you can generate kind of event ItemImported and on the UI side you react on this event by changing the text of the progress bar (under the progress bar).

ItemImported can be in your import class.
Under "UI side" I mean the class which is responsible for interaction with UI, for example some ViewModel or just your MainWindow.cs which knows about conrols on UI.

To change the text on UI you will need to use for example Dispatcher.Invoke (if it's a desktop app) or something to interact with UI properly while the import goes.

Comment: I am using Webapi to send list in request but i want a call back when it enters entry in db for each iteration of loop so that i can show the number of data successfully imported.

Comment: Then you can ignore my answer, it's for desktop :)

Comment: True, Web api i am using is restless which does not maintain state thats why it is looking impossible to show that.

Comment: To not have minuses on your question add more details in it about techs you use and paraphrase the title in more specific, for example "How to notify UI side from backend using WebApi"

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.